# Adding and removing dynamic div in html

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, ajax

I am trying to build a website. There is options for users to post comments.
I am planning to show a few (say 5) comments in the intial fetch and an option to load more comments.
I am using jquery and was thinking to create the html divs dynamically for the same based on the number of comments.Is this the best idea ?

Also , is there a way to remove the dynamically created elements so that on re-entry to the page I have only the static elements and if needed attach the dynamic elements ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

jQuery offers some really handy tools on how to dynamically create DOM elements. You will want to use the `.append()` method to insert new elements.

For example, say you had a HTML structure with a container for all of your comments, and a few comments already:

```
<div id="comments_container">
    <div class="comment">
        This is a comment!
    </div>
    <div class="comment">
        This is another comment!
    </div>
    <div class="comment">
        Comment 3!
    </div>
</div>
```

You could use the following code to dynamically add more comments:

```
$("#comments_container").append('<div class="container">'+comment_data+'</div>');
```

Every new dynamically added comment will appear at the bottom of the comments `<div>`. If you want to add the comments at the top of the comments container, then use `prepend()` instead of `append()`.

> Also , is there a way to remove the dynamically created elements so that on re-entry to the page I have only the static elements and if needed attach the dynamic elements ?

Yes. Any elements dynamically inserted using `prepend()` and `append()` will disappear when the user reloads or revisits the page.